# MySQL Workbench: Migration Wizard not available

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I dont have the option of "Migration Wizard" under "database" in MySQL Workbench V8.0 CE

Anything needs to be installed/updated to get the same?

Comment: In menu under 'Database'/'Migration Wizard' ?

Comment: @Luuk yes, correct , edited the question

Comment: It shows a text to me : "the Migration Wizard uses ODBC to connect to the source database...."   If might b possible that, if you do not have an ODBC driver installed, that the option is not visible in the menu (but i cannot test this right now...)